# The invalid JSON. The missing symbol

Tags: json

I have a JSON file with not valid structure. The error occures on the line 181 (propery "edu_data"). In VS code the description of problen is "expecting comma (json 514)". In the [online JSON validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#) the error message is "Expecting comma or ], not colon".

I've checked the JSON manully a lot of times but can't figure out where I'd missed the symbol. So please help me to find the missing symbol.

```
{
"response":"success",
"description":"Ok",
"objects":[
    {
        "type":"hr_application",
        "object":{
            "appl_id":98,
            "type":"hr",
            "state":200,
            "user_state":200,
            "business_dept":"pyat",
            "loader_user_name":"X5\\M.Sergeev",
            "loader_comment":"",
            "load_time":"2019-09-25T14:35:38.91",
            "user_name":"x5\\Anna.Ivanina",
            "system_comment":"Иванов Иван Сергеевич",
            "pi_data":[
                {
                    "pi_id":11111,
                    "pi_relation":"main",
                    "state":"other",
                    "fio_data":[
                        {
                            "is_actual":true,
                            "f":"Иванов",
                            "i":"Иван",
                            "o":"Сергеевич",
                            "norm_f":"иванов",
                            "norm_i":"иван",
                            "norm_o":"сергеевич"
                        }
                    ],
                    "d":6,
                    "m":10,
                    "y":1978,
                    "citizenship":"",
                    "gender":"",
                    "b_place":"г. Обнинск",
                    "inn":"123456789012",
                    "is_enterp":false,
                    "is_enterp_comment":"",
                    "aff_with_x5":false,
                    "driver_data":{
                        "license_info":"",
                        "car_info":""
                    },
                    "id_document_data":[
                        {
                            "is_actual":true,
                            "type":"pasp",
                            "series":"1234",
                            "number":"123123",
                            "issuer":"УВД города Обнинска",
                            "issue_date":"07.03.2011",
                            "norm_series":"1234",
                            "norm_number":"123123",
                            "is_valid":1
                        }
                    ],
                    "adr_data":[
                        {
                            "type":"reg",
                            "value":"г Обнинск, ул Ленина, д 2, кв 1",
                            "norm_value":" г Обнинск, ул Ленина, д 2, кв 1"
                        },
                        {
                            "type":"reg_tmp",
                            "value":"",
                            "norm_value":""
                        },
                        {
                            "type":"liv",
                            "value":" г Обнинск, ул Набережная, д 7, кв 1",
                            "norm_value":" г Обнинск, ул Набережная, д 7, кв 1"
                        }
                    ],
                    "tel_data":[
                        {
                            "type":"mob",
                            "value":"79111111111",
                            "norm_value":"9111111111"
                        }
                    ],
                    "email_data":[
                        {
                            "type":"pers",
                            "value":"IvanObninsk@gmail.com",
                            "norm_value":"ivanobninsk@gmail.com"
                        }
                    ],
                    "le_data":[
                        {
                            "pi_relation":"employee",
                            "state":"other",
                            "name":"ООО Компания в которой работал кандидат",
                            "full_name":"",
                            "legal_form":"",
                            "inn":"",
                            "ogrn":"",
                            "kpp":"",
                            "okpo":"",
                            "okonh":"",
                            "reg_date":"",
                            "reg_place":"",
                            "okved_data":[
                                {
                                    "value":"Услуги"
                                }
                            ],
                            "tel_data":[
                                {
                                    "type":"mob",
                                    "value":"",
                                    "norm_value":""
                                }
                            ],
                            "email_data":[
                                
                            ],
                            "adr_data":[
                                {
                                    "type":"leg",
                                    "value":"г Москва пр. Коммунистический 34",
                                    "norm_value":" г Москва пр. Коммунистический 34"
                                }
                            ],
                            "pi_position":"инженер",
                            "pi_respons":"",
                            "pi_start_date":"01.2012",
                            "pi_end_date":"05.2016",
                            "pi_man_info":"",
                            "pi_quit_reas":"смена работы",
                            "pi_ach_info":"",
                            "pi_is_last":true
                        },
                        {
                            "pi_relation":"employee",
                            "state":"other",
                            "name":"ООО Компания 23",
                            "full_name":"",
                            "legal_form":"",
                            "inn":"",
                            "ogrn":"",
                            "kpp":"",
                            "okpo":"",
                            "okonh":"",
                            "reg_date":"",
                            "reg_place":"",
                            "okved_data":[
                                {
                                    "value":"торговля"
                                }
                            ],
                            "tel_data":[
                                {
                                    "type":"mob",
                                    "value":"",
                                    "norm_value":""
                                }
                            ],
                            "email_data":[
                                
                            ],
                            "adr_data":[
                                {
                                    "type":"leg",
                                    "value":"",
                                    "norm_value":""
                                }
                            ],
                            "pi_position":"риэлтор",
                            "pi_respons":"",
                            "pi_start_date":"07.2016",
                            "pi_end_date":"07.2019",
                            "pi_man_info":"",
                            "pi_quit_reas":"маленькая зп",
                            "pi_ach_info":"",
                            "pi_is_last":false
                        },
                        "edu_data":[
                            {
                                "type":"main",
                                "name":"Институт г Обнинск ",
                                "speciality":"Менеджер",
                                "start_year":"2006",
                                "end_year":"2011"
                            }
                        ],
                        "prosp_dept":"Перекресток Офис",
                        "prosp_position":"менеджер по аренде",
                        "prosp_comment":"",
                        "prosp_vac_inf_src":"",
                        "res_data":[
                            {
                                "id":123456,
                                "hr_appl_id":123123,
                                "pi_id":11111,
                                "res_user_name":"X5\\Anna.Ivanina ",
                                "res":-1,
                                "comment":"Комментарии аналитика 1",
                                "inner_comment":"Внутренний комментарий 1",
                                "create_time":"2019-09-26T10:44:26.353",
                                "res_code_data":[
                                    ""
                                ],
                                "res_text_data":[
                                    
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "id":123458,
                                "hr_appl_id":123123,
                                "pi_id":11111,
                                "res_user_name":"X5\\Ivanov ",
                                "res":-1,
                                "comment":"Комментарии аналитика 2",
                                "inner_comment":"Внутренний комментарий 2",
                                "create_time":"2019-09-27T11:04:26.353",
                                "res_code_data":[
                                    
                                ],
                                "res_text_data":[
                                    
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "appr_data":[
                            {
                                "id":98766,
                                "hr_appl_id":123123,
                                "pi_id":11111,
                                "init_user_name":"X5\\Igor.Sergeev",
                                "dest_email":"Am.Soglasuushaya@x5.ru",
                                "dest_comment":"",
                                "email_message_id":0,
                                "res":1,
                                "comment":" ",
                                "create_time":"2019-09-26T10:15:35.833",
                                "update_time":"2019-09-26T12:50:40.567",
                                "url":"65565GGHJUGFHF8FJF8EOE0RURKF8EL",
                                "security_manager_appr_data":[
                                    {
                                        "id":1234,
                                        "hr_appl_id":123123,
                                        "pi_id":11111,
                                        "pi_appr_id":98766,
                                        "security_manager_user_namee":"x5\\Alek.Fedrenko",
                                        "security_manager_res":1,
                                        "create_time":"2019-09-26T10:15:35.883",
                                        "update_time":"2019-09-26T10:21:59.293"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "id":98564,
                                "hr_appl_id":123123,
                                "pi_id":11111,
                                "init_user_name":"X5\\Vlad.Petrov ",
                                "dest_email":"M.Disapprovov@x5.ru",
                                "dest_comment":"",
                                "email_message_id":0,
                                "res":0,
                                "comment":" ",
                                "create_time":"2019-09-26T10:15:04.567",
                                "update_time":"2019-09-26T10:15:04.567",
                                "url":"DHDHDHD5D6DHD7D7DD7D7D9DKD9DDLSDKF9F9994F",
                                "security_manager_appr_data":[
                                    {
                                        "id":123451,
                                        "hr_appl_id":123123,
                                        "pi_id":11111,
                                        "pi_appr_id":98564,
                                        "security_manager_user_namee":"x5\\Petr.Andreev ",
                                        "security_manager_res":0,
                                        "create_time":"2019-03-11T10:15:04.583",
                                        "update_time":"2019-03-11T10:15:04.583"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "chk_stage":"checked_pos",
                        "appr_allowed":false,
                        "res_allowed":true,
                        "email_message_data":[
                            
                        ],
                        "aux_info":""
                    },
                    {
                        "pi_id":11111,
                        "pi_relation":"mother",
                        "state":"other",
                        "fio_data":[
                            {
                                "is_actual":true,
                                "f":"Иванова",
                                "i":"Галина",
                                "o":"Петровна",
                                "norm_f":"лыкова",
                                "norm_i":"галина",
                                "norm_o":"сергеевна"
                            }
                        ],
                        "d":30,
                        "m":11,
                        "y":1958,
                        "citizenship":"",
                        "gender":"",
                        "b_place":"",
                        "inn":"",
                        "is_enterp":false,
                        "is_enterp_comment":"",
                        "aff_with_x5":false,
                        "driver_data":{
                            "license_info":"",
                            "car_info":""
                        },
                        "id_document_data":[
                            
                        ],
                        "adr_data":[
                            {
                                "type":"liv",
                                "value":"",
                                "norm_value":""
                            }
                        ],
                        "tel_data":[
                            
                        ],
                        "email_data":[
                            
                        ],
                        "le_data":[
                            {
                                "pi_relation":"employee",
                                "state":"other",
                                "name":"Пенсионер",
                                "full_name":"",
                                "legal_form":"",
                                "inn":"",
                                "ogrn":"",
                                "kpp":"",
                                "okpo":"",
                                "okonh":"",
                                "reg_date":"",
                                "reg_place":"",
                                "okved_data":[
                                    
                                ],
                                "tel_data":[
                                    
                                ],
                                "email_data":[
                                    
                                ],
                                "adr_data":[
                                    
                                ],
                                "pi_position":"",
                                "pi_respons":"",
                                "pi_start_date":"",
                                "pi_end_date":"",
                                "pi_man_info":"",
                                "pi_quit_reas":"",
                                "pi_ach_info":"",
                                "pi_is_last":false
                            }
                        ],
                        "edu_data":[
                            
                        ],
                        "prosp_dept":"",
                        "prosp_position":"",
                        "prosp_comment":"",
                        "prosp_vac_inf_src":"",
                        "res_data":[
                            
                        ],
                        "appr_data":[
                            
                        ],
                        "chk_stage":"ready",
                        "appr_allowed":false,
                        "res_allowed":false,
                        "email_message_data":[
                            
                        ],
                        "aux_info":""
                    },
                    "file_data":[
                        
                    ],
                    "is_manual":false,
                    "is_postponed":false
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: you're missing a closing square bracket,`"le_data"` is an array, so you need a `}],` instead of a `},` on line 180. (see line 370, where there is an appropriate closing square bracket)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your Valid JSON, it was the array symbol creating the issue. Array closing was missing before **edu_data** key.

```
{
"response": "success",
"description": "Ok",
"objects": [{
    "type": "hr_application",
    "object": {
        "appl_id": 98,
        "type": "hr",
        "state": 200,
        "user_state": 200,
        "business_dept": "pyat",
        "loader_user_name": "X5\\M.Sergeev",
        "loader_comment": "",
        "load_time": "2019-09-25T14:35:38.91",
        "user_name": "x5\\Anna.Ivanina",
        "system_comment": "Иванов Иван Сергеевич",
        "pi_data": [{
                "pi_id": 11111,
                "pi_relation": "main",
                "state": "other",
                "fio_data": [{
                    "is_actual": true,
                    "f": "Иванов",
                    "i": "Иван",
                    "o": "Сергеевич",
                    "norm_f": "иванов",
                    "norm_i": "иван",
                    "norm_o": "сергеевич"
                }],
                "d": 6,
                "m": 10,
                "y": 1978,
                "citizenship": "",
                "gender": "",
                "b_place": "г. Обнинск",
                "inn": "123456789012",
                "is_enterp": false,
                "is_enterp_comment": "",
                "aff_with_x5": false,
                "driver_data": {
                    "license_info": "",
                    "car_info": ""
                },
                "id_document_data": [{
                    "is_actual": true,
                    "type": "pasp",
                    "series": "1234",
                    "number": "123123",
                    "issuer": "УВД города Обнинска",
                    "issue_date": "07.03.2011",
                    "norm_series": "1234",
                    "norm_number": "123123",
                    "is_valid": 1
                }],
                "adr_data": [{
                        "type": "reg",
                        "value": "г Обнинск, ул Ленина, д 2, кв 1",
                        "norm_value": " г Обнинск, ул Ленина, д 2, кв 1"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "reg_tmp",
                        "value": "",
                        "norm_value": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "liv",
                        "value": " г Обнинск, ул Набережная, д 7, кв 1",
                        "norm_value": " г Обнинск, ул Набережная, д 7, кв 1"
                    }
                ],
                "tel_data": [{
                    "type": "mob",
                    "value": "79111111111",
                    "norm_value": "9111111111"
                }],
                "email_data": [{
                    "type": "pers",
                    "value": "IvanObninsk@gmail.com",
                    "norm_value": "ivanobninsk@gmail.com"
                }],
                "le_data": [{
                        "pi_relation": "employee",
                        "state": "other",
                        "name": "ООО Компания в которой работал кандидат",
                        "full_name": "",
                        "legal_form": "",
                        "inn": "",
                        "ogrn": "",
                        "kpp": "",
                        "okpo": "",
                        "okonh": "",
                        "reg_date": "",
                        "reg_place": "",
                        "okved_data": [{
                            "value": "Услуги"
                        }],
                        "tel_data": [{
                            "type": "mob",
                            "value": "",
                            "norm_value": ""
                        }],
                        "email_data": [

                        ],
                        "adr_data": [{
                            "type": "leg",
                            "value": "г Москва пр. Коммунистический 34",
                            "norm_value": " г Москва пр. Коммунистический 34"
                        }],
                        "pi_position": "инженер",
                        "pi_respons": "",
                        "pi_start_date": "01.2012",
                        "pi_end_date": "05.2016",
                        "pi_man_info": "",
                        "pi_quit_reas": "смена работы",
                        "pi_ach_info": "",
                        "pi_is_last": true
                    },
                    {
                        "pi_relation": "employee",
                        "state": "other",
                        "name": "ООО Компания 23",
                        "full_name": "",
                        "legal_form": "",
                        "inn": "",
                        "ogrn": "",
                        "kpp": "",
                        "okpo": "",
                        "okonh": "",
                        "reg_date": "",
                        "reg_place": "",
                        "okved_data": [{
                            "value": "торговля"
                        }],
                        "tel_data": [{
                            "type": "mob",
                            "value": "",
                            "norm_value": ""
                        }],
                        "email_data": [

                        ],
                        "adr_data": [{
                            "type": "leg",
                            "value": "",
                            "norm_value": ""
                        }],
                        "pi_position": "риэлтор",
                        "pi_respons": "",
                        "pi_start_date": "07.2016",
                        "pi_end_date": "07.2019",
                        "pi_man_info": "",
                        "pi_quit_reas": "маленькая зп",
                        "pi_ach_info": "",
                        "pi_is_last": false
                    }
                ],
                "edu_data": [{
                    "type": "main",
                    "name": "Институт г Обнинск ",
                    "speciality": "Менеджер",
                    "start_year": "2006",
                    "end_year": "2011"
                }],
                "prosp_dept": "Перекресток Офис",
                "prosp_position": "менеджер по аренде",
                "prosp_comment": "",
                "prosp_vac_inf_src": "",
                "res_data": [{
                        "id": 123456,
                        "hr_appl_id": 123123,
                        "pi_id": 11111,
                        "res_user_name": "X5\\Anna.Ivanina ",
                        "res": -1,
                        "comment": "Комментарии аналитика 1",
                        "inner_comment": "Внутренний комментарий 1",
                        "create_time": "2019-09-26T10:44:26.353",
                        "res_code_data": [
                            ""
                        ],
                        "res_text_data": [

                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 123458,
                        "hr_appl_id": 123123,
                        "pi_id": 11111,
                        "res_user_name": "X5\\Ivanov ",
                        "res": -1,
                        "comment": "Комментарии аналитика 2",
                        "inner_comment": "Внутренний комментарий 2",
                        "create_time": "2019-09-27T11:04:26.353",
                        "res_code_data": [

                        ],
                        "res_text_data": [

                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "appr_data": [{
                        "id": 98766,
                        "hr_appl_id": 123123,
                        "pi_id": 11111,
                        "init_user_name": "X5\\Igor.Sergeev",
                        "dest_email": "Am.Soglasuushaya@x5.ru",
                        "dest_comment": "",
                        "email_message_id": 0,
                        "res": 1,
                        "comment": " ",
                        "create_time": "2019-09-26T10:15:35.833",
                        "update_time": "2019-09-26T12:50:40.567",
                        "url": "65565GGHJUGFHF8FJF8EOE0RURKF8EL",
                        "security_manager_appr_data": [{
                            "id": 1234,
                            "hr_appl_id": 123123,
                            "pi_id": 11111,
                            "pi_appr_id": 98766,
                            "security_manager_user_namee": "x5\\Alek.Fedrenko",
                            "security_manager_res": 1,
                            "create_time": "2019-09-26T10:15:35.883",
                            "update_time": "2019-09-26T10:21:59.293"
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 98564,
                        "hr_appl_id": 123123,
                        "pi_id": 11111,
                        "init_user_name": "X5\\Vlad.Petrov ",
                        "dest_email": "M.Disapprovov@x5.ru",
                        "dest_comment": "",
                        "email_message_id": 0,
                        "res": 0,
                        "comment": " ",
                        "create_time": "2019-09-26T10:15:04.567",
                        "update_time": "2019-09-26T10:15:04.567",
                        "url": "DHDHDHD5D6DHD7D7DD7D7D9DKD9DDLSDKF9F9994F",
                        "security_manager_appr_data": [{
                            "id": 123451,
                            "hr_appl_id": 123123,
                            "pi_id": 11111,
                            "pi_appr_id": 98564,
                            "security_manager_user_namee": "x5\\Petr.Andreev ",
                            "security_manager_res": 0,
                            "create_time": "2019-03-11T10:15:04.583",
                            "update_time": "2019-03-11T10:15:04.583"
                        }]
                    }
                ],
                "chk_stage": "checked_pos",
                "appr_allowed": false,
                "res_allowed": true,
                "email_message_data": [

                ],
                "aux_info": ""
            },
            {
                "pi_id": 11111,
                "pi_relation": "mother",
                "state": "other",
                "fio_data": [{
                    "is_actual": true,
                    "f": "Иванова",
                    "i": "Галина",
                    "o": "Петровна",
                    "norm_f": "лыкова",
                    "norm_i": "галина",
                    "norm_o": "сергеевна"
                }],
                "d": 30,
                "m": 11,
                "y": 1958,
                "citizenship": "",
                "gender": "",
                "b_place": "",
                "inn": "",
                "is_enterp": false,
                "is_enterp_comment": "",
                "aff_with_x5": false,
                "driver_data": {
                    "license_info": "",
                    "car_info": ""
                },
                "id_document_data": [

                ],
                "adr_data": [{
                    "type": "liv",
                    "value": "",
                    "norm_value": ""
                }],
                "tel_data": [

                ],
                "email_data": [

                ],
                "le_data": [{
                    "pi_relation": "employee",
                    "state": "other",
                    "name": "Пенсионер",
                    "full_name": "",
                    "legal_form": "",
                    "inn": "",
                    "ogrn": "",
                    "kpp": "",
                    "okpo": "",
                    "okonh": "",
                    "reg_date": "",
                    "reg_place": "",
                    "okved_data": [

                    ],
                    "tel_data": [

                    ],
                    "email_data": [

                    ],
                    "adr_data": [

                    ],
                    "pi_position": "",
                    "pi_respons": "",
                    "pi_start_date": "",
                    "pi_end_date": "",
                    "pi_man_info": "",
                    "pi_quit_reas": "",
                    "pi_ach_info": "",
                    "pi_is_last": false
                }],
                "edu_data": [

                ],
                "prosp_dept": "",
                "prosp_position": "",
                "prosp_comment": "",
                "prosp_vac_inf_src": "",
                "res_data": [

                ],
                "appr_data": [

                ],
                "chk_stage": "ready",
                "appr_allowed": false,
                "res_allowed": false,
                "email_message_data": [

                ],
                "aux_info": ""
            }
        ],
        "file_data": [

        ],
        "is_manual": false,
        "is_postponed": false
    }
}]
}
```